# How to redirect to the requested jsp page after login success?

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, servlet-filters

I have developed a filter which will check first if a session exists or not if a request made by the client, and It will render the requested pages directly if the session exists, if not the filter will redirect the user to the servlet (LoginNow.do) which will show a login page inorder to create a session object on login success.

But I still have a little problem with redirecting the user to the requested page after login success. I have added the requested page as a parameter in the URL if its link on the index page clicked, which is gonna be concatenated to the URL of login.jsp until the login precess suceeded, at that moment this page will be rendered to the user. However the login page does not show at this stage, and I dont know why?

```
http://localhost:8080/ACMEDemo/LoginNow.do?referer=/ACMEDemo/content1.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your application folder involved in it.

```
 http://localhost:8080/ACMEDemo/LoginNow.do?referer=content1.jsp
```

Then

```
 response.sendRedirect("./" + request.getParameter("referer"));
```

Comment: That is a very good idea. Thanks